# Call ExectuorService with time interval - android

Tags: android, httprequest, executorservice, background-task

i used a **custom thread** to fetch data in the background every 1 second by making a thread goes to sleep, but my App crashes and throws exception **OutOfMemoryError**. Now i read a documentation in android developer and i understand that using custom thread is bad practice as it is difficult to manage the memory consistency. but finally  i found **ExecutorService** very interesting when we need to do some tasks on background So, i decided to use it.

As You know the ExecutorService is like below:

```
public void executeTask()
{
    ExecutorService executroService = new Executor.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executroService.execute(new Runnable()
    {
       @Override
       publi void run()
       {
          // now execute the server request
       }  
    });

}
```

Now how can i achive calling to executorService every 1 second untill the user goes to onpause() state or untill the user shifts from the current activity to another activity? if i use a custom thread to call that service, the App goes to crash. so how can i achive that ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService)

It can schedule commands to run after a given delay,
or to execute periodically.

Here is a code that implements this

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     Runnable beeper = () -> System.out.println("beep");
     ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     Runnable canceller = () -> beeperHandle.cancel(false);
     scheduler.schedule(canceller, 1, HOURS);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hey bro seems your answer interesting. After i checked it and works fine i will mark it as answer.

Comment: Sure.. let me know if you get stuck somewhere

Comment: yeah the code works fine because it is wrriten by google developers but that code works for 1 hour every 10 seconds. but could you make it  to call every 1 second untill the user enteres to onPause() state ? which means every 1 second untill the user closes the App or changes the current Activity to another activity ?

Comment: you have to cancel the scheduler ...Override the onPause in your app and cancel the scheduler..Since in both the scenarios on Pause will be called

Comment: Ok good what would be the total time to call ?  how much time should i do that ? but basically i should not assign an integer value for total time to be scheduled because i don't know how much time is the user interact with the user-interface. or should i use big time like untill 100 hour then when the user enters to onPause(), cancle the scheduler ?

Comment: No not all.> whatever the value you put the schedular will get cancelled until you restart it again so shouldn't be an isseu